# Pycharm error loading modules: ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, importerror

I am using an anaconda environment which has some modules installed via "conda install" and others using a pip install wheel(?). It seems that these modules are not found by pycharm when I select the interpreter. I can uncheck "use conda package manager" which then shows all the correct packages in pycharm, but when I try to run my code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Data/Code/UU/SWS/SWS_project/Functions/Gullies_to_natural_spaces.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env37\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Which is confusing because when I activate the environment using anaconda prompt and run the same script from inside Jupyter notebook it works perfectly?!

Comment: Which PyCharm version do you use?

Comment: @PavelKarateev I'm using Community 2019.3

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this question ?